# HTTP GET request get HTML page code instead of expected json Response

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

/*Here is the code*/

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=http://www.fifacoinservice.com/api/v1"></head><body></body></html>
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: PipeGuard
Date: Mon, 15 Jun 2015 10:29:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 605
Connection: close

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<h1>400 Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. Sorry for the inconvenience.<br/>
    Please report this message and include the following information to us.<br/>
    Thank you very much!</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>URL:</td>
        <td>http://_</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Server:</td>
        <td>5.254.102.236.r00t-services.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Date:</td>
        <td>2015/06/15 10:29:32</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr/>Powered by PipeGuard</body>
</html>
```

Here is my call

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.server.com/api/v1");
            String query = "api_key=q5EicSKs027cjut7qhZk&method";

            //make connection
            URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();

            //use post mode
            urlc.setDoOutput(true);
            urlc.setAllowUserInteraction(false);

            //send query
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(urlc.getOutputStream());
            ps.print(query);
            ps.close();

            //get result
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlc
                .getInputStream()));
            String l = null;
            while ((l=br.readLine())!=null) {
                System.out.println(l);
            }
            br.close();
```

Comment: Bad request - *The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications*

Comment: Why you are sending api key separately instead of part of the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `Accept` header.

```
urlc.addRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
```

### Update

Your server may not support application/json datatype. You can check it by `curl`.

```
curl -X POST  -H "Accept: application/json" --data 'api_key=q5EicSKs027cjut7qhZk&method' http://www.server.com/api/v1
```

Comment: @AnandTagore i updated my answer and now i tested it, it working well.

Comment: Hi still the response is an html page as given:- <html><head><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=http://www.server.com/api/v1/?api_key=q5EicSKs027cjut7qhZk&method=PlayerInformation&console=playstation&amount=100000&timestamp=1434029691&hash=7bac215348688e813e6cf0c496e2a780&playername=har&limit=10"></head><body></body></html>

Comment: @AnandTagore Are you sure your server application supports application/json data format? Have you try it from any other rest client application like postman or paw? After adding this line your application is saying server that it accepts application/json data. It should work if your server really supports it.

Comment: You are right, it's a server side issue and they solved it. And now it's working

Comment: @bhdrkn. In my case, request works on git bash but not in postman. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like below using `Apache HTTP client`?

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.server.com/api/v1");

        post.setHeader("api_key", "q5EicSKs027cjut7qhZk&method");

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

        JSONObject o = new JSONObject(result.toString());
```